# Linux 2D Array values not setting

Tags: arrays, linux, bash

Only [0, 1] doesn't set value.

```
echo "while=${group_member_total_count}, ${j}, ${data[${group_member_total_count}, ${j}]}"
```

And I get a result like this

```
while=0, 0, 2
while=0, 1, 1025
while=0, 2, 0
while=0, 3, 0
while=0, 4, 2
while=0, 5, 4
while=0, 6, 0
while=1, 0, 2
while=1, 1, 1
while=1, 2, 0
while=1, 3, 0
while=1, 4, 2
while=1, 5, 4
while=1, 6, 0
```

But when I set directly, it doesn't make sense.
Where is 1025?

```
echo "${data[0, 0]} ,${data[1, 0]}"
echo "${data[0, 1]} ,${data[1, 1]}"
echo "${data[0, 2]} ,${data[1, 2]}"
echo "${data[0, 3]} ,${data[1, 3]}"
echo "${data[0, 4]} ,${data[1, 4]}"
echo "${data[0, 5]} ,${data[1, 5]}"
echo "${data[0, 6]} ,${data[1, 6]}"

2 ,2
1 ,1
0 ,0
0 ,0
2 ,2
4 ,4
0 ,0
```

Why?

Comment: Please, read [how to ask useful questions aka MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and then edit yours so somebody can help you better.

Comment: Here's an easier way to reproduce your problem: `var[1,2]=42; var[0,2]=1337; echo "${var[1,2]}"`

Comment: Thank You. I found on a linux webpage that structure value only support one dimension. So, I just changed my script.